# Finding dynamic tensors in a tflite model

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am currently experiencing the following error when loading a tflite model using the C API:

> ERROR: Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors.

The tflite model can be found [here](https://ufile.io/lopo5egf). It is a tflite conversion of the [LEAF model](https://github.com/google-research/leaf-audio).

The input and output tensors upon inspection seem to have static sizes. I have inspected the model with Netron and cannot find any dynamic tensors, however I may have overlooked. Is there a way to see which tensors specifically are causing an issue with their dynamic tensors?

Comment: Are you trying to run your model with any delegates, for example, GPU delegate or NNAPI delegate? This message only appears when the delegate can not handle the given model from either GPU delegate or NNAPI delegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though there are no dynamic size tensors in the graph, the above graph has a control flow op, While op. Currently, graphs with control flow ops are regarded as dynamic graphs and those graphs are not supported through the hardware acceleration delegates, which allow the only static graph structure.

Comment: Is there any way to detect this in the C API before the interpreter builder sends an error?

Comment: Sorry. Currently, there is no such feature available yet. Thanks for the valuable feedback. As you said, delegate compatibility checking can be a separate tool.

Comment: No worries, thanks for building a great product!

Comment: What is the best way to identify the use of control flow ops in a model, or other ways to determine if a model is using dynamic graphs? @JaesungChung

Comment: @luca992 It would be better to ask the question in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency in your gradle file to support ops model:

```
org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.8.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).